# Pytorch and numpy least squares with an intercept: performance complications

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, least-squares

I am performing regression analysis on some reasonably large vectors (for now, working with numpy and other scientific tools is ok if I leave the computer working overnight) but they will grow by several factors eventually, and so I was looking to improve performance, moving the implementation to pytorch.

The regression is fairly simple. I have 2 vectors, `predictions` and `betas`, with dimensions (750, 6340) and (750, 4313) respectively. The least squares solution I am looking for is `predictions * x = betas` where x would have dimensions (6340, 4313), but I have to account for intercepts in the regression. With numpy I solved this by iterating through the second dimension in `predictions`, creating a vector with each column + a column of ones, and passing that as the first argument

```
for candidate in range(0, predictions.shape[1])): #each column is a candidate
    prediction = predictions[:, candidate]
    #allow for an intercept by adding a column with ones
    prediction = np.vstack([prediction, np.ones(prediction.shape[0])]).T
    sol = np.linalg.lstsq(prediction, betas, rcond=-1)
```

Question number 1 would be: is there a way to avoid iterating over each candidate in order to allow the least squares calculation to account for an intercept? That would improve computation time by a lot.

I tried using [statsmodels.regression.linear_model.ols](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) which allows for this by default (you can add a `-1`to the formula if you want it removed), but using this approach either forces me to iterate over each candidate (using `apply` was appealing but didn't really improve computation time noticeably) or there is something I'm missing. Question 1.5 then: can I use this tool in such a way or is all there is to it?

Similarly in pytorch I would do

```
t_predictions = torch.tensor(predictions, dtype=torch.float)
t_betas_roi = torch.tensor(betas, dtype=torch.float)
t_sol = torch.linalg.lstsq(t_predictions, t_betas_roi)
```

And it's fast indeed, but I'm missing the intercept here. I reckon if I did this with numpy instead of iterating as I do it would also be much faster but either way, if question 1 has a solution I imagine it could be similarly applied here, right?